# Error building DRBD 9 from tarball on Oracle Linux 6

Tags: linux, oracle-linux

Currently I'm trying to test DRBD 9 (drbd-9.0.21-1 & drbd-utils-9.13.0)  on Oracle Linux 6 system (the same for production), and it's isolated from outside network, so using yum is out of question (and I can't upgrade the distro since it will be used on the running production). Currently, I'm building it using the tarball.

[The documentation](https://www.linbit.com/drbd-user-guide/drbd-guide-9_0-en/#s-linbit-packages) doesn't mention anything about required packages and versions, so, I execute `make` and fetching the needed rpms and using [this Centos 6 guide](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=drbd&f=1) and [this Centos 7 guide](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=drbd9&f=1) packages.

Finally, I use [this Centos 6 guide](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=drbd&f=1) (I know the DRBD version there is 8.4, but I have to make do with it since there's no other guide on my case, and [this Centos 7 guide](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=drbd9&f=1) is pretty similar, without drbdmanage, which it got replaced with linstor recently) to build it.

I can run `make kmp-rpm`  for DRBD9 and `./configure` for drbd-utils just fine, but when I run `make rpm` for the dbrd-utils, it gives me this error (I run this as root):

```
RPM build errors:
    %defattr doesn't define directory mode so file mode defined in %defattr is used for directory: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/drbd-9.13.0-1.el6.x86_64/lib/drbd
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/drbd-9.13.0-1.el6.x86_64/usr/sbin/drbdmon
    %defattr doesn't define directory mode so file mode defined in %defattr is used for directory: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/drbd-9.13.0-1.el6.x86_64/usr/lib/drbd
    %defattr doesn't define directory mode so file mode defined in %defattr is used for directory: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/drbd-9.13.0-1.el6.x86_64/var/lib/drbd
    %defattr doesn't define directory mode so file mode defined in %defattr is used for directory: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/drbd-9.13.0-1.el6.x86_64/var/run/drbd
    File not found by glob: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/drbd-9.13.0-1.el6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man8/drbdmon-*
make: *** [rpm] Error 1


# ls /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/drbd-9.13.0-1.el6.x86_64/lib/
drbd  udev

# ls /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/drbd-9.13.0-1.el6.x86_64/usr/sbin/
drbdadm  drbdmeta  drbdsetup

# ls /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/drbd-9.13.0-1.el6.x86_64/usr/lib/
debug  drbd  ocf

# ls /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/drbd-9.13.0-1.el6.x86_64/var/lib/
drbd

# ls /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/drbd-9.13.0-1.el6.x86_64/var/run/
drbd

# ls /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/drbd-9.13.0-1.el6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man8/
drbd-8.3.8.gz     drbdadm-8.4.8.gz   drbdmeta-8.3.8.gz   drbdsetup-8.4.8.gz
drbd-8.4.8.gz     drbdadm-9.0.8.gz   drbdmeta-8.4.8.gz   drbdsetup-9.0.8.gz
drbd-9.0.8.gz     drbddisk-8.3.8.gz  drbdmeta-9.0.8.gz
drbdadm-8.3.8.gz  drbddisk-8.4.8.gz  drbdsetup-8.3.8.gz
```

From my understanding, it couldn't find drbdmon. Is there any way to solve this? Am I missing a something or is it not possible to build DRBD 9 on EL6?

Comment: This might be useful : [build-install-from-source](https://github.com/fghaas/drbd-documentation/blob/master/users-guide/build-install-from-source.txt).

Comment: @harrymc I couldn't find the `+configure+ script` and couldn't execute `autoconf` from the expanded tarball (no input file)

Comment: @harrymc Building a rpm package also doesn't work with that guide since there's no `configure` file. I think that guide is outdated since it's intended for version 8.4.0, and the file in `wget http://oss.linbit.com/drbd/8.4/drbd-8.4.0.tar.gz` doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: The current stable version is [drbd-9.0.25-2](https://www.linbit.com/linbit-software-download-page-for-linstor-and-drbd-linux-driver/#drbd9). Linbit [recommends](https://www.linbit.com/drbd-user-guide/drbd-guide-9_0-en/#s-from-source) using their tarballs rather than github. It is also [said](https://lists.linbit.com/pipermail/drbd-user/2016-July/022509.html) that `make` alone is enough for compiling version 9.

Comment: But I can make the rpm for drbd just fine, the problem is I couldn't make the rpm for drbd-utils, which right now I've tried using various versions with the same error (couldn't find drbdmon). I found [this guide](https://www.theurbanpenguin.com/compiling-drbd-sds-from-source/), I will try it later and see if it works (although it's not building the rpm).

Comment: Try maybe the [linbit drbd-utils release v9.0.0](https://github.com/LINBIT/drbd-utils/releases?after=v9.3.0).

Comment: From README.drbd-utils inside their provided tarball:  With DRBD module version 8.4.5, we split out the management tools
  into their own repository at https://github.com/LINBIT/drbd-utils
  (tarball at http://links.linbit.com/drbd-download)

  That started out as "drbd-utils version 8.9.0",
  has a different release cycle,
  and provides compatible drbdadm, drbdsetup and drbdmeta tools
  for DRBD module versions 8.3, 8.4 and 9.

  Again: to manage DRBD 9 kernel modules and above,
  you want drbd-utils >= 9.3 from above url.

Comment: Mixing versions is something that I always avoid, and you are also using older versions of everything. You will need to find here someone that encountered your exact error (but it's not me).

Comment: Did you ever try to install the pre-built for RedHat?

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m not sure I understand what you meant by pre-built for RedHat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finally able to build the drbd-utils by using newer version of gcc. The built-in gcc version of my oracle linux is 4.4, which doesn't have C++11.

I'm using [this guide to use newer gcc temporarily in the shell.](https://gist.github.com/stephenturner/e3bc5cfacc2dc67eca8b)